# JsonMappingException on a Hadoop program with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, jackson, noclassdeffounderror, cloudera-quickstart-vm

Seeing JsonMappingException on a simple Hadoop program when running in Eclipse(Kepler) with Cloudera QuickStart VM

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonMappingException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$1.run(Job.java:595)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:581)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:612)
    at MaxTemperature.main(MaxTemperature.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 8 more
```

As suggested by many, tried adding jackson jars from the quickstart VM but no success.

Answer (score 6):

After spending couple of hours debugging, found solution by adding below jars:

```
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13
```

Hope this will save sometime for starters who may face similar issue on running hadoop programs(using eclipse) over Cloudera quickstart VM.